# Adding an element into wildchar list cause compile error

Tags: java, generics

I hava a list contains future tasks, future type is unknown, so I create a list with wildcard type `?`, but when I add an element to the list, a compile error happens.

This is the code:

```
private List<Pair<String, Future<?>>> futureTasks = Collections.synchronizedList(
        new ArrayList<Pair<String, Future<?>>>(8));

// taskId is a string
futureTasks.add(Pair.makePair(taskId, getExecutors().submit(
    new Callable<String>() {
        public String call() {
            try {
                return exportAccountSrcTask(tmpFile); // return a string
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("failed to export account src", e);
            }
            return null;
    }}))
);
```

Compiler error:

> The method `add(Pair<String,Future<?>>)` in the type `List<Pair<String,Future<?>>>` is not applicable for the arguments `(Pair<String,Future<String>>)`

Comment: Why can't you declare it as `List<Pair<String, Future<String>>>`?

Comment: the future may not be string

Comment: Then declare it as `List<Pair<String, Future<Object>>>`. As for why you can't `.add()` with the wildcard: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3716920/ and http://stackoverflow.com/q/69702/

Comment: @MattBall This is actually a different issue because it involves a nested wildcard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting an error because a `Pair<String, Future<String>>` is not a `Pair<String, Future<?>>`. Generic types are not covariant.

You can however type `futureTasks` as `List<Pair<String, ? extends Future<?>>>`. Then you'll be able to add a `Pair<String, Future<String>>` to it.

**EDIT:**

To explain this better, think of trying to assign an object to a variable instead of adding it to a list. If we have a `List<T>`, we can only add an object if it *is a* `T`. So this is really the same situation:

```
Pair<String, Future<String>> pairOfStringAndFutureOfString;
Pair<String, Future<?>> pairOfStringAndFutureOfSomething;

// incompatible types
pairOfStringAndFutureOfSomething = pairOfStringAndFutureOfString;
```

Again, this isn't allowed because generics aren't covariant. Why? Consider what could happen if they were:

```
Future<Integer> futureOfInt;
Future<?> futureOfSomething;
futureOfSomething = futureOfInt; // a future of int is a future of something

Pair<String, Future<String>> pairOfStringAndFutureOfString;
Pair<String, Future<?>> pairOfStringAndFutureOfSomething;

// pretend this is legal
pairOfStringAndFutureOfSomething = pairOfStringAndFutureOfString;

// danger!
pairOfStringAndFutureOfSomething.setRight(futureOfSomething);
Future<String> futureOfString = pairOfStringAndFutureOfString.getRight();

//sometime later...
String string = futureOfString.get(); //ClassCastException
```

We got `futureOfString` to point to something that was actually a `Future<Integer>`. But this didn't even cause a `ClassCastException` right away because thanks to type erasure, the JVM only saw `Future`s. This situation is called "heap pollution" - where a variable points to an object it shouldn't have been allowed to. The actual runtime error only happened once we tried to unwrap `futureOfString`.

So that explains why generics aren't covariant. Let's look at the workaround:

```
Pair<String, ? extends Future<?>>
pairOfStringAndSomethingThatIsAFutureOfSomething;
```

That variable name is a mouthful but I wanted it to describe exactly what's going on here. Before, the second type argument was *exactly* `Future<?>`. Now, we're saying that it's "some unknown type, which is or extends `Future<?>`. For example, it could be `Future<?>`, it could be `Future<String>`, it could even be `MySpecialFuture<Integer>`.

We're voluntarily giving up some information about the type of this variable in order to relax what can be assigned to it. Now, this is legal:

```
pairOfStringAndSomethingThatIsAFutureOfSomething = pairOfStringAndFutureOfString;
```

The compiler protects against the earlier "heap pollution" scenario by preventing this unknown type from being "consumed":

```
//compiler error - nothing can be legally passed into setRight
pairOfStringAndSomethingThatIsAFutureOfSomething.setRight(futureOfSomething);
```

To learn more about these retrictions, see this post: [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs)

Comment: @jamee See my edit and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Seems I can add both Pair<String, Future<String>> and Pair<String, Future<Integer>> into List<Pair<String, ? extends Future<?>>>, and no compile error.

Comment: @jamee Yep, that's correct, because they are both a `Pair<String, ? extends Future<?>>`. What you won't be able to do is re-set the future in a `Pair<String, ? extends Future<?>>` after you read it back from the list - but I'm assuming you don't need to do that.

Comment: @jamee It's important to realize there's a big difference between top-level wildcards and nested wildcards. See this post for a lot more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546745/multiple-wildcards-on-a-generic-methods-makes-java-compiler-and-me-very-confu